# Number Theory : Find the group of A such that $A=\{x \in \mathbb{Z}:\frac{x^3-3x+2}{2x+1}\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the group A such that  $A=\{x \in \mathbb{Z}:\frac{x^3-3x+2}{2x+1}\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ ?

Polynomial Long Division we get
$\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x}{4}-\frac{11}{8}+\frac{27}{8\left(2x+1\right)}$

but how i can from here find all x such that $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ ??

i did use the hint for $y = 2x+1$ so that  $x =\frac{y-1}{2}$

made the equation to be $\frac{(y-1)^3}{8}-\frac{3(y-1)}{2}+2=\frac{y^3-3y^2-9y+27}{8}$

$\frac{\frac{y^3-3y^2-9y+27}{8}}{y}=\frac{y^3-3y^2-9y+27}{8y}$

I can not understand with the help of the clues, can some 1 some formal proof ?

Comment: Well, a natural first step might be to try some examples.  Have you found some integers in $A$?

Comment: What happens to the last fraction and the sum if $(2x+1)$ is not a divisor of $27$?

Comment: @lulu of course i found some integers in A but i want to see way .

Comment: Please edit your post to indicate your efforts.

Comment: @lulu yeah i did

Comment: Is $A=\{-14,-5,-2,-1,0,1,4,13\}$  a group?

Comment: @Raffaele Yeah that's true how u did this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2x+1|x^3-3x+2\iff 2x+1|8(x^3-3x+2)$

$\iff 2x+1|8(x^3-3x+2)-(2x+1)^3=-12x^2-30x+15$

$\iff 2x+1|3(2x+1)^2-12x^2-30x+15=-18x+18$

$\iff 2x+1|9(2x+1)-18x+18=27$

$\iff x\in \{-14,-5,-2,-1,0,1,4,13\}.$

Comment: Thanks , this is the full sol for the problem ? @DanielWainfleet

Comment: Yes. But don't call it a group, as "group" has a special meaning in algebra.

Comment: what its mean the right and left arrow ? if and only if ? 
you can maybe write it like a formal proof ?

Comment: thank you for the proof , but i dont understand why u use the right and left arrow you can edit it for made its formal proof please?

Comment: $\iff$ means "if and only if". In LaTex it is \iff. And "iff" is often used in plain text  for "if and only if". What I wrote $is$ formal.

Comment: simple question why if u multiply the equation by 8 its must divided the 2x+1 ?

Comment: $2x+1$  is odd so $2x+1$ divides $y$ iff $2x+1$ divides $2y, 4y, 8y,$ etc.

Comment: thank u. Any chance on please elaberationg on ur answer , because i didn't understand the changes between every line and the steps of the equation.

Comment: your proof its very good but if u can explain each step because i didnt understand the changes please .

Comment: If B\ne 0 then B|C means C/B\in \Bbb Z. So if B|D then (B|C\iff B|C\pm D). Consider B=2x+1 and D=E(2x+1)^n with E\in\Bbb Z and n\in \Bbb N

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $2x+1$ is odd for all integers $x$, we have that $\frac{x^3-3x+2}{2x+1}\in\mathbb Z$ if and only if $\frac{2(x^3-3x+2)}{2x+1}\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: 1. from where i can know that if and only if $\frac{2(x^3-3x+2)}{2x+1}\in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

2. so the next equation is $\frac{x^3-3x+2}{x+\frac{1}{2}}\in \mathbb{Z}$ ??

Comment: The New Polynomial is $x^2-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{11}{4}+\frac{27}{4\left(2x+1\right)}$ just from where to search what number can be divided to $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ ??

Comment: 1. One direction is obvious, if you multiply an integer by $2$, you get an integer. The other follows from the fact that $2x+1$ and $2$ are relatively prime, so if $2x+1$ divides $2(x^3-3x+2)$, it must divide $x^3 - 3x + 2$.

Comment: 2. No, forget rational numbers, the trick with multiplying by $2$ is so that the numerator and the denominator have the same leading coefficient. In this particular case, $2x^3-6x+4 = x^2(2x+1) -x^2 -6x + 4$, so you lose the $x^2$ and reduced the problem to finding $x$ such that $\frac{-x^2-6x+4}{2x+1}$ is an integer. Proceed as above. @atb

Comment: Can you please give us full sol with your hints i am get in trouble :S

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $2x+1=y$

$$x^3-3x+2=(y-1)^3/8-3(y-1)/2+2=\dfrac{y^3-3y^2-9y+27}8$$ which will be divisible by $y$

$\iff y$ divides $y^3-3y^2-9y+27$ as $y$ is odd

Comment: Didn't check your work, but according to mine, seems to me that it should be $27$, not $29$, right?

Comment: @Ennar, thanks for your observation. Actually after submission, the latex was not rendered properly.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanks , i use your hint when i divides by $y$ its by $8y$ and its even right ? so how can make step forward i dont get it

Comment: @atb, It's clear that $y$ has to divide $27$ .Now we need to check for all the possible values of $y$

Comment: i just need to find all the number divided by 27 because i got 8y and i need to find all the numbers such that 27 divided by 8? maybe can write small explanation :D?

Comment: @atb. If $x\ge1, y\ge3$  so, the options for $y$ are $$3,9,27$$  example, if $y=27, x=13$  $$x^3-3x+2=13(13^2-3)+2, 2x+1=?$$